# MongoDB Aggregation from Array

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am very new to mongoDB, and I am looking to aggregate some data from one collection to another that I will create with **$out**. Basically I have a collection of data that has information stored inside an array, and I want to put data into the new collection, if that same data has been inserted into the array at least once. What would be the best function to do this. I was looking at **$filter** and **$elemMatch**.

Basically if any of the **truck's registration** number appears in any of the user type mechanic **maintenances** arrays at least once, then I want to save that information in a new collection like {"registration":"truck-registration"}, with no duplicates.

What would be the best way to do this?

These are just a few of many database inserts (there are many users and many more trucks).

> Trucks

```
db.transport.insert ( {"_id":"GFT008", "TRUCK": { "registration":"GFT008", "capacity":40000, "weight":15000, "status":"AVAILABLE"} });
db.transport.insert ( {"_id":"PKR008", "TRUCK": { "registration":"PKR008", "capacity":22000, "weight":8800, "status":"AVAILABLE"} });  
db.transport.insert ( {"_id":"QRT834", "TRUCK": { "registration":"QRT834", "capacity":5550, "weight":400, "status":"USED"} } );
```

> Employees

```
db.transport.insert ( {"_id":"6", "EMPLOYEE": { "e#":"6", "name":"Michael Jones", "dob":"05-OCT-65", "address":"23 Waterloo Ave. Surry Hills, NSW 2502", "hiredate":"12-JAN-93","position":"mechanic","licence":"7773","status":"ON_LEAVE","experience":"STANDARD","maintenances":[{"registration":"QRT834","time":"40","maintenance date":"12-JUN-99"},{"registration":"QRT834","time":"40","maintenance date":"15-JUN-98"},{"registration":"SYF777","time":"30","maintenance date":"01-AUG-98"},{"registration":"SYF777","time":"30","maintenance date":"05-AUG-95"},{"registration":"SYF777","time":"30","maintenance date":"06-AUG-00"},{"registration":"LUCY01","time":"200","maintenance date":"12-MAR-97"},{"registration":"SYF777","time":"30","maintenance date":"02-AUG-00"},{"registration":"PKR768","time":"200","maintenance date":"12-AUG-00"},{"registration":"QRT834","time":"200","maintenance date":"30-JUN-00"},{"registration":"SYF777","time":"300","maintenance date":"02-AUG-02"},{"registration":"PKR768","time":"460","maintenance date":"12-AUG-02"},{"registration":"LUCY01","time":"40","maintenance date":"29-JUL-02"},{"registration":"QRT834","time":"40","maintenance date":"30-JUN-02"}]} } );
```

Comment: Please list your documents, you can use `$unwind` to extract array into objects

Comment: @NuOne, updated

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:

Live demo at [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zTdAE6RNYA3)

```
db.employee.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$EMPLOYEE.maintenances"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "transport",
      localField: "EMPLOYEE.maintenances.registration",
      foreignField: "TRUCK.registration",
      as: "matches"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "matches": {
        $size: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$EMPLOYEE.maintenances.registration",

    }
  }
])
```

It's a multi-stage aggregation:
- Unwind array
- Join unwinded stage with transport records
- Filter records with exactly one(?) match
- and finally - remove duplicates by grouping

Result:

```
[{"_id": "QRT834"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. If I wanted to put this acquired data into a new collection would I add `{"$out":"new-collection-name"}` at the end? And if I wanted it to gather data with instances of 'at least one match' (one to many) not 'with only one match', would it be `{ $match: { "matches": { $size: {$gte: 1 }}}}`

Comment: You are right about `$out` stage. Unfortunately, you can't see the result in the playground. https://mongoplayground.net/p/zTdAE6RNYA3 As for the size - your `$size` - based version would generate an error, but you can try something like `{ $match: { "matches.0" : { $exists : true }}}` - try it out in the playground. However, since the `transport._id` seems to be the same as `TRUCK.registration`, there is no way you'll get more than one match here.

Comment: Here is the updated mongo playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/pKLtzVLZimC with {"registration":vid} and $size $gte condition just for completion.